# Deploying website using ftploy to digitalocean

Tags: digital-ocean, deploying

I cannot connect with digitalocean server when iam trying to deploy website using ftploy.Server connection showing failed.I have used ssh while making droplet.Help me to sove this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If digital ocean is setup to use SFTP, then on ftploy try setting the port to 22.